# Added Firebase Analytics to project but still no update in Firebase Console

Tags: android, firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

Here is my source code of MainActivity

```
    private void initializeFirebaseAnalytic() {
          firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        firebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
        firebaseAnalytics.setMinimumSessionDuration(500);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK your events events only send if you builded apk is in release mode.

you can send an event like this:

```
FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics =  FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(App.getInstance());

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, action);
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, label);
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(category, bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to download the config file (google-services.json) file from the firebase console and put it in your project (app/ folder).Also you can use the firebase assistant for doing all the configurations needed automatically.After that you could use logEvent() method to send event to the firebase dashboard.